# Vectors of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm trying to use the following vectors of pointers to objects of a custom class `tree_node`

```
std::vector<tree_node*> branch;
```

in my code i need to use branch in the following function

```
void search_tree::tree_tries(tree_node& a){
  a.visits++; //member of class tree_node
  branch.push_back(&a);
  if(a.nodes>0){
     branch_position++;
     int nodo=rand()%a.nodes;
     tree_tries(a.children_nodes[nodo]);
  }
  else{
     backtrack();//another function, enters branch[] pointers members to modify them
  }
}
```

My problem stands in how to manage the `branch` vector. I need to use the `push_back` function since i don't know how many and what objects i'll have to point to, and using `push_back` keep things easy. After ending this function when the `backtrack()` ends, i need to "reset" the vector's pointers, i.e. i need them to be erased so that `push_back` will start allocating from the beginning of the vector.

I'm not sure `delete` is useful here, the objects I'm pointing to are already constructed objects i need to keep and use in various ways. I'm just wondering if there's an efficient way to just delete the pointer without touching the pointed object.

Comment: Why do people always strive for making their lives difficult by using raw pointers and vectors of pointers?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the vector is of pointers and not objects?

Comment: because I haven't studied smart pointers yet, just wondering if there was a way

Comment: Just `clear()` the vector. Since it only contains pointers and not actual objects, they will not be deleted automatically.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hello again. Yes, i need to keep track of the various objects i select using `rand()` and to modify some member values using `backtrack()`.

Comment: @luigi - Why not spend a few hours studying/experimenting with smart pointers instead of using that time debugging your existing code?

Comment: @EdHeal I'll do it for sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector.clear()` will just empty the vector without touching the objects being pointed at. That's it :)